# Complex database queries vs scheduled storing of data and stored procedures

Tags: mysql, database-design, stored-procedures, view

I'm building a system using MySQL that allows tasks to be managed and created. Tasks can be either

- a one-off task to be completed by a fixed date
- repeating tasks, starting on a fixed date and repeating every N days

A simplified schema looks like

```
Tasks
========================

| id |   name     | date     | repeats |
|  1 |  Backup X  | 2011-... | 0       |
|  2 |  Backup Y  | 2011-... | 1       |
```

Now, let's say I want to run a query on this data set:

```
SELECT $N - mod(datediff(NOW(), Task.date), $N) AS datediff, Task.name 
  FROM tasks Task
  ORDER BY datediff, Task.date;
```

where N is the repeat interval for a task.

As you can see, I have to sort by **either** `Task.date` or `datediff`. What I really need is to be able to sort on one field and for `datediff` to be dependent on whether or not a task repeats.

In psuedocode, the following query would be more appropriate:

```
SELECT
  IF(Task.repeats = 1)
    // Get the number of days until next repeat on a repeating event
    $N - mod(datediff(NOW(), Task.date), $N) AS datediff
  ELSE
    // Get number of days until non-repeating task expires
    datediff(NOW(), Task.date) AS datediff
```

- Stored procedures are one option, but are more difficult to manage then in application code.
- Views are another option. But MySQL views are not very efficient.

So, **I am thinking of setting up a CRON job that populates a table** with updated data every 5 minutes or so. Then I will be able to query this table on the relevant fields.

I think this method would scale better when tasks become more complicated:

> e.g. users could give each task a very precise repeat interval using crontab syntax which would require quite a lot of processing in application code to work out the datediff on all tasks.

I appreciate your thoughts on this since i've had a tendency lately to avoid complex queries and stored procedures. Perhaps this is overkill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably over complicated the viable options in this case by not having looked into MySQL's control flow functions nearly enough.

One solution i'm goin with at the minute is

```
SELECT IF(Task.repeat, repeats_expression, non_repeats_expression) as date_diff;
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds to me like you should store/run these with MySQL Events

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-events.html

Comment: Ah yes, that might well work in those cases where i'm using MySQL > 5.1, in this case I'm not. In essence, it's the same principle as the CRON job to populate a table - is this a common thing, and why is it preferable to writing complex queries, using views or utilising stored procedures from your point of view?

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.dc.doc/dc/c_spbenefits.htm